# how to enlarge the size of an image fetched from database using only php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I want to know is there any inbuilt function in php through which I can display an image greater than the size stored in database(i.e. greater than the original size).

I know it can be done using the HTML/CSS properties `height` and `width` but I want it done through php only.

I tried `imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);` but it takes file or directory name in place of `$filename` and my image is in a database.

Here is a part of my code:

```
    while( $result=mysqli_fetch_array($runquery))
    {
        echo'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'base64_encode($result['image']).'"/>';
    }
```

Comment: Why are you saving image in database (base64 encoded?) and not only reference to this file on file system?

Comment: Do not store images in your DB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: @justinas yes i can store it in file on file system but in case if i am storing it in database....can i get a possible solution and will  imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); work in that case

Answer (score 2):

Load your image with [`imagecreatefromstring`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php). Then resize it with [`imagecopyresized`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php).

Also I would suggest you to only save the paths to your image in the database.

Comment: thanks for your valuable comment ....some how it is not working in my case .... i think it is better if i d0 some serious editing work and save my images in file system first .......thanks again for the valuable link....

Comment: can you please clarify which data type to use for storing image location in database....actually '\' is omitted from image location value by MySQL which is creating problem

Comment: got it .... actually i have to use '\' two times .i.e.  images\\1.jpg earlier i was writing images\1.jpg......

Comment: @user3151681 yes, you have to escape the backslashes. Look at `addslashes` http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: can you help with these question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388964/image-is-not-getting-displayed-on-the-web-page-instead-the-text-loading-is?noredirect=1#comment39598062_25388964

Answer (score 1):

Get Imagick ready and call following function

```
bool Imagick::setImageExtent ( int $columns , int $rows )
```

Reference: [Imagick::setImageExtent](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageextent.php)

Comment: ImageMagick is not installed on every system, so it may not fit op's needs for an inbuilt function